# Why do I get random fatal errors - 'Class 'Proxies\MyEntityProxy' not found"?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I keep getting (what seems to be) random PHP fatal errors complaining:

> Fatal error: Class 'Proxies\MyEntityProxy' not
>   found in
>   /vendor/doctrine/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Proxy/ProxyFactory.php
>   on line 94

I'll usually just refresh, and everything works. I'm using Symfony 2.0.9 (about to upgrade to 2.0.11 right now). I've never seen this error before, and am not sure how to fix it.

Comment: This usually indicates a caching problem.  Are you working strictly in dev mode or switching to production on occasion?

Comment: I'd say 98% of the time I'm in dev mode, the rest is in production. But I've been seeing these errors occur while in dev mode.

Comment: Are you using an opcode cache? I encounter the same error from time to time, mostly during deployments on a server that runs APC. Reloading apache usually works. I've been trying to figure out the exact cause with no luck though.

Comment: I have facing the same issue. Disabling APC didn't help. I am switching between dev - prod occasionally.

Comment: I have the same issue. Is there any solution? I'm doing continuous parallel call to an API page.